# How to change color of header link in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

How to change the color and font size? Thank you

Comment: inspect your css classes and change as required

Comment: Can you provide the Url website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color and font through CSS like below.

```
.wrapper .page-header #header-nav{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: @Thad Steven Alaban Maraon mark it as useful.. :) Thanks